# trouble adding SMA fit line to ggplot - geom_segment() nor geom_abline() don't match

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add the trendline from an SMA (standardized major axis) fit to my ggplot. However, when I extract the coefficients from the SMA and give them to geom_abline() the line extends over the entire plot instead of clipping to the data. The natural solution to this would be use a geom_segment() instead, manually calculating the endpoints of the line. However, when I do this the lines don't match each other and neither match the SMA fit. What's going on here?

I am aware that you can use the plot function directly on an sma object but I would prefer to use ggplot

Note: this is my first time asking a question so my apologies if I'm missing something!

Edit: I am using a log-log axis, which I suspect may be part of the issue.

Reproducible version below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(smatr) #for the SMA

# sample data set
x <- rlnorm(100, meanlog = 10)
var <- rlnorm(100, meanlog = 10)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=x+var)


# fit using an SMA
sm <- sma(x~y, data = df, log = "xy")

# get sma coefficients into a data.frame
bb <- data.frame(coef(sm))
bb <- bb %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Coef") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Coef", values_from = "coef.sm.")

## calculate end coordinates for segment
bb$min_x <- min(df$x, na.rm = TRUE)
bb$max_x <- max(df$x, na.rm = TRUE)
bb <- bb %>%
  mutate(min_y = (slope*min_x) + elevation) %>%
  mutate(max_y = (slope*max_x) + elevation) 

# plot into ggplot
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(shape=21) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')+
  scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10') +
  geom_abline(data=bb,aes(intercept=elevation,slope=slope), color = "blue") 
p1 + geom_segment(data=bb, aes(x=min_x, xend=max_x, y=min_y, yend=max_y), color = "orange")

#this is the plot from the smatr package for comparison
plot(sm)
```